# Can't figure out how to make a python coin toss program loop back to a certain point once the whole process of the toss has been completed

Tags: python, loops

I have been banging my head against the wall for a few hours now trying to figure this out so any help is greatly appreciated. What I'm trying to do is loop the program upon a Y input for a Y/N question, specifically when Y is inputed I want it to react the way it does as shown in the sample output.

Here is my code:

```
import random
def main():
    name = eval(input("Hello user, please enter your name: "))
    print("Hello", name ,"This program runs a coin toss simulation")
    yn = input("Would you like to run the coin toss simulation?(Y/N):")
    if yn == Y:

    elif yn == N:
        print("Ok have a nice day!")

    heads = 0
    tails = 0
    count = tails + heads
    count = int(input("Enter the amount of times you would like the coin to     flip: "))
    if count <= 0: 
        print("Silly rabbit, that won't work")
    while tails + heads < count:
        coin = random.randint(1, 2)
        if coin ==1:

            heads = heads + 1
        elif coin == 2:

            tails = tails + 1
    print("you flipped", count , "time(s)")
    print("you flipped heads", heads , "time(s)")
    print("you flipped tails", tails , "time(s)")
main()
```

Here is the sample output that I'm looking for:

```
Hello user, please enter your name: Joe
Hello Joe this program runs a coin toss simulation
Would you like to run the coin toss simulation?(Y/N):Y
Enter the amount of times you would like the coin to flip:50
you flipped 50 times
you flipped heads 26 times
you flipped tails 24 times
Would you like to run another coin toss simulation?(Y/N):Y
Enter the amount of times you would like the coin to flip:100
you flipped 100 times
you flipped heads 55 times
you flipped tails 45 times
Would you like to run another coin toss simulation?(Y/N):N
Ok have a nice day!
```

Comment: You need quotes in line 6. Y is a variable "Y" is a string. Also there are other problems (you need to do something or just pass under line 6 etc...) But I assume you were asking this. And finally please write your code in your question next time, so it's easy to reproduce.

Comment: just put that code in, my bad I'm new here

Answer (score 0):

I think you should say on line 6 `if yn == 'Y'` and not `if yn == Y`. You treat Y as a variable while it is actually a string from the input.

Answer (score 0):

To run your coin toss simulation multiple times you can put it inside a `while` loop.

Your `if yn == Y:` test won't work because you haven't defined the variable `Y`, so when Python tries to execute that line you get a `NameError`. What you actually should be doing there is to test the value of `yn` against the *string* `'Y'`.

I've made a couple of other minor adjustments to your code. I got rid of that potentially dangerous `eval` function call, you don't need it. I've also made a loop that asks for the desired flip count; we break out ofthe loop when `count` is a positive number.

```
import random

def main():
    name = input("Hello user, please enter your name: ")
    print("Hello", name , "This program runs a coin toss simulation")
    yn = input("Would you like to run the coin toss simulation?(Y/N): ")
    if yn != 'Y':
        print("Ok have a nice day!")
        return

    while True:
        heads = tails = 0
        while True:
            count = int(input("Enter the amount of times you would like the coin to flip: "))
            if count <= 0: 
                print("Silly rabbit, that won't work")
            else:
                break

        while tails + heads < count:
            coin = random.randint(1, 2)
            if coin ==1:
                heads = heads + 1
            else:
                tails = tails + 1

        print("you flipped", count , "time(s)")
        print("you flipped heads", heads , "time(s)")
        print("you flipped tails", tails , "time(s)")

        yn = input("Would you like to run another coin toss simulation?(Y/N): ")
        if yn != 'Y':
            print("Ok have a nice day!")
            return

main()
```

---

This code is for Python 3. On Python 2 you should use `raw_input` in place of `input`, and you should also put

from **future** import print_function

at the top of the script so you get the Python 3 `print` function instead of the old Python 2 `print` _statement.

---

There are several improvements that can be made to this code. In particular, it should handle a non-integer being supplied for the count. This version will just crash if it gets bad input. To learn how to fix that, please see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).